# Set form size does not match the size of displayed form

Tags: c#, .net, size, controls, resolution

My question is very simple but I searched and searched and could not find the answer.
I am using `.NET 4.0 c#`. I size my displayed form width to exact 10 inches (measured by ruler) on my screen, and `this.Size.Width` shows 946. I expect 960 because `HorizontalResolution` shows 96. I tried with different sizes and always got ratio 94.6 instead of 96.

This is definitely not measurement error, but what causes the discrepancy?

Comment: Why the down vote? can you give me the explanation?

Comment: Compatibility.  The DPI of your monitor is almost never *exactly* 96.  They keep 96 because changing it causes so many problems, programmers don't write scaling code.  And the size itself is almost always a lie from the operating system, necessary to hide the fact that Aero creates windows with much fatter borders.  Those 2 pixel borders of old were getting too hard to hit with the mouse.  Without that lie the client area of the window would be too small to fit the content.

Comment: Although I don't see this as a 'coding' question, it does show that utilizing a physical resource to measure a screen will result in incorrect sizing if used to create a form/window.

Comment: Hans, Thank you so much for your explanation. So it is impossible to set Form or any control to exact physical size (e.g., 10 inches)?